# Oracle batch command (fail in code, but works in sql-developer)

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, .net-core

I use **Oracle.ManagementDataAccess.Client** as ORM for connection with Oracle db. There is sql for update data. It looks similat to this

```
 UPDATE tabel SET  ...
 /
 UPDATE tabel SET  ...
 /
```

execution in code looks like that

```
 OracleCommmand command;
 command.CommandText = "code from above";
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get error **ORA-00936 Missing express**, but when I copy/paste my update commands in sql developer. Everything works fine. I assume there is problem with executing OracleCommand in my code? Any idea/hints?

Comment: your code is not a single SQL, and ExecuteNonQuery submits it like it is, so it fails. You have to execute each update separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle forbids multiple statements in a single command (to help prevent SQL injection attacks).

If you run:

```c#
OracleCommmand command;
command.CommandText = "
UPDATE tabel SET attr1 = 'abc'
/
UPDATE tabel SET attr2 = 'def'
/
";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Then it will fail.

You need to run the statements individually (and without the statement terminator). Something like:

```c#
OracleCommmand command1;
command1.CommandText = "UPDATE tabel SET attr1 = 'abc'";
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

OracleCommmand command2;
command2.CommandText = "UPDATE tabel SET attr2 = 'def'";
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When you run it in SQL Developer then the IDE will split the statements up and run them as individual commands.